# Share MongoDB across 2 Docker containers having different MongoDB versions

Tags: mongodb, docker

Already a fully-fledged mongo v3.2 instance with data is running on a container.

I need to create a mongo v3.6 container instance with the same data as v3.2.

I do not have space to clone the data on the server.

I tried a lot of stuff.

Can I point to the data of the v3.2 from my v3.6 so that it is shared and I save space?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Don't know if it would work(because of different versions of mongodb).

You can create a sharded cluster and add your old DB as a shard.

Answer (score 0):

I got the space cleared.

Got the dump and made a new instance of mongo.

It works like a charm now.

The sharing volume was corrupting the data.